# Angular dynamic module federation NullInjectorError when importing a standalone component with dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation, angular-standalone-components

I am trying to create the shell application as a dashboard with no routing, where I display multiple cards and the card content would be the remote (the microfrontend standalone component).

I have been trying to implement a similar solution to this tutorial: https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/dynamic-module-federation-with-angular/.

I followed the above link because that was the one that fit my needs the most, because all the other tutorials involved routing (specifying the path for each standalone component, and loading just 1 module that defines the routes) and everything worked that way.

What I’d like to achieve is to have a shell application, which during run time (based on a json file downloaded via http) can load components from different remotes.

I am using the latest *@angular-architects/module-federation(16.0.4)* package with angular v16.
I have created a fork based on Manfred Steyer’s work to demonstrate my problem: https://github.com/zkristof97/module-federation-with-angular-dynamic-workflow-designer

As long as I have a component that does not inject any dependencies, the exposed standalone component can be used in the shell with no problem, for example the [EnrichComponent](https://github.com/zkristof97/module-federation-with-angular-dynamic-workflow-designer/blob/master/projects/mfe2/src/app/enrich.component.ts).

When I provide an injectionToken in [bootstrap.ts](https://github.com/zkristof97/module-federation-with-angular-dynamic-workflow-designer/blob/master/projects/mfe2/src/bootstrap.ts) (e.g. [MY_TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN](https://github.com/zkristof97/module-federation-with-angular-dynamic-workflow-designer/blob/master/projects/mfe2/src/app/test.di.ts)) and I just serve the remote app that defines the [EnrichComponent](https://github.com/zkristof97/module-federation-with-angular-dynamic-workflow-designer/blob/master/projects/mfe2/src/app/enrich.component.ts), everything works fine, the console.log also executes on init.

But when I try to use the [EnrichComponent](https://github.com/zkristof97/module-federation-with-angular-dynamic-workflow-designer/blob/master/projects/mfe2/src/app/enrich.component.ts) in the shell, with the injectionToken injected, I get the NullInjectorError.
[image]

Comment: You didn't provide any value for the `MY_TEST_INJECTION_TOKEN` in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell doesn't bootstrap the other applications, this is just done in the standalone apps when you access their `index.html`.

The shell only loads the component from remote entry file.

Your shell needs to provide the token required by the `EnrichComponent`.

Comment: So when I load a remote standalone component (the EnrichComponent), the bootstrapping does not occur for the AppComponent (in this example)?

Does your answer mean if a component has some root provided dependencies like httpClient and 10+ others, they all individually have to be provided on the component level?

Comment: The `HttpClient` should only be provided by the shell. For the rest it depends if it's shared or not.

Comment: What about a custom service which is not provided in root, should they be moved to a library and that library should be used in both the shell, and the bootstrapping of the remote?

Comment: Only share it if you need to have it accross different apps (or if it need to be access from different routes/components).